# How to create event registration based on participant roles?

Tags: civievent, registration, online-registration

Related to [this question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/27605/civievent-how-to-collect-different-custom-data-for-different-event-participant) and to the respective [extension](https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.multipleparticipantroleforevent):

**Is there a solution for this task working with CiviCRM 5.47.3 for Joomla?**

Thanks in advance for your hints!